# video with iframe doesn't display on Android Webview

Tags: android, video, iframe, webview, video-streaming

I am working on Android project (API level 8) displaying `WebView` from another website which I cannot change the code of these website. I am having trouble with video clip in `WebView` on some devices that does not enable Force GPU rendering (in settings --> Developer options). The following codes are the codes that I read from the website

```
<center><iframe width=\"500\" height=\"315\" src=\"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/bf7wpubnyIE\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen><\/iframe><\/center>  <br \/>
```

and

```
<center> <iframe frameborder=\"0\" width=\"480\" height=\"323\" src=\"http:\/\/www.dailymotion.com\/embed\/video\/xrmnk1\"><\/iframe> <\/center><br \/>
```

On Android side I already enable several settings which are

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); 
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); 
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

I believe I can't use `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` since I am working on API level 8

When I turn off Force GPU  rendering the error on logcat are shown as follows

```
06-20 14:04:24.455: W/webview(28201):   at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:9468)
06-20 14:04:24.455: W/webview(28201):   at android.webkit.WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(WebView.java:2186)
06-20 14:04:24.455: W/webview(28201):   at com.tss.one.MainDetail$1.run(MainDetail.java:144)
06-20 14:04:24.455: W/webview(28201):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-20 14:04:24.533: V/PhoneStatusBar(10977): setLightsOn(true)
06-20 14:04:24.697: I/ActivityManager(10909): Displayed com.tss.one/.MainDetail: +614ms
06-20 14:04:27.197: D/libEGL(28201): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
06-20 14:04:27.205: D/libEGL(28201): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
06-20 14:04:27.221: D/libEGL(28201): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
06-20 14:04:27.229: D/libEGL(28201): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
06-20 14:04:27.729: E/Web Console(28201): Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL http://www.youtube.com/embed/bf7wpubnyIE. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
06-20 14:04:27.729: E/Web Console(28201):  at null:1
06-20 14:04:27.838: E/libEGL(28201): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
06-20 14:04:27.838: D/ShaderProgram(28201): couldn't load the vertex shader!
06-20 14:04:27.838: D/ShaderProgram(28201): couldn't load the vertex shader!
06-20 14:04:27.838: D/ShaderProgram(28201): couldn't load the vertex shader!
06-20 14:04:27.838: D/ShaderProgram(28201): couldn't load the vertex shader!
06-20 14:04:27.838: D/ShaderProgram(28201): couldn't load the vertex shader!
06-20 14:04:28.213: D/dalvikvm(28201): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3468K, 17% free 20475K/24519K, paused 3ms+2ms
06-20 14:04:29.783: E/Web Console(28201): Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1 at http://static1.dmcdn.net/js/gen/widget/pack/player.js.v91ec0434953824904:1
06-20 14:04:29.791: D/MediaPlayer(28201): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
06-20 14:04:29.791: I/AwesomePlayer(10888): setDataSource_l('http://www.dailymotion.com/cdn/H264-512x384/video/xrmnk1.mp4?auth=1340348666-9f8ec9001ccce92feec18d9419b07065&helper=0')
06-20 14:04:29.791: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(10888): connect on behalf of uid 10124
06-20 14:04:29.791: I/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(10888): connect to http://www.dailymotion.com/cdn/H264-512x384/video/xrmnk1.mp4?auth=1340348666-9f8ec9001ccce92feec18d9419b07065&helper=0 @0
06-20 14:04:33.291: I/SampleTable(10888): There are reordered frames present.
06-20 14:04:33.299: I/OMXCodec(10888): [OMX.TI.DUCATI1.VIDEO.DECODER] AVC profile = 66 (Baseline), level = 30
06-20 14:04:33.299: I/OMXCodec(10888): [OMX.TI.DUCATI1.VIDEO.DECODER] video dimensions are 512 x 344
06-20 14:04:33.299: I/OMXCodec(10888): [OMX.TI.DUCATI1.VIDEO.DECODER] Crop rect is 512 x 344 @ (0, 0)
06-20 14:04:34.432: I/OMXCodec(10888): [OMX.TI.DUCATI1.VIDEO.DECODER] video dimensions are 640 x 448
06-20 14:04:34.432: I/OMXCodec(10888): [OMX.TI.DUCATI1.VIDEO.DECODER] Crop rect is 512 x 344 @ (0, 0)
06-20 14:04:34.604: I/OMXCodec(10888): [OMX.TI.DUCATI1.VIDEO.DECODER] video dimensions are 640 x 448
06-20 14:04:34.604: I/OMXCodec(10888): [OMX.TI.DUCATI1.VIDEO.DECODER] Crop rect is 512 x 344 @ (32, 24)
06-20 14:04:34.612: W/SoftAAC(10888): Sample rate was 44100 Hz, but now is 22050 Hz
06-20 14:04:39.666: I/NuCachedSource2(10888): ERROR_END_OF_STREAM
```

Comment: I also have this problem, and since Android 4.0 default Browser and Chrome app can overcome this (at least for Youtube), it should be a way to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's problem of hardware acceleration. Try to disable it :

```
@TargetApi(11)
private void disableHardwareAcceleration() {
    if(getCustomApp().isHarwareAccelerateDisable() && android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        Log.e(TAG, "disable HardwareAcceleration");
        webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
}
```